# How to add elements to a vector in a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, cell-array

Let's say I have a cell array `raweeg` each cell of which is a matrix with time points in the first column and some markers in the second. I want to create a vector to store the time points, when the marker is not equal to -1. I found a non-elegant (and not working) way to create a vector of zeros of size 1x1 and then to append the following values in a loop.

P.S.: There are exactly 96 non-"-1" values and corresponding time points.

```
startpoints = zeros(1,1);

for i = length(raweeg{1,1}(:,1))
   if raweeg{1,1}(i,2) ~= -1
   startpoints(end+1,1) = raweeg{1,1}(i,1); 
   end
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Any luck with the answer? The error is identified as missing `1:`, and a vectorized solution is given.  If that works, please accept.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to the system and it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorize it like this, for a given cell of `raweeg`:

```
startpoints = raweeg{1,1}(raweeg{1,1}(:,2) ~= -1, 1);
```

This is called [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Just be sure your markers are not generated with floating point computations, or the comparisons will likely fail often.

---

P.S.  The problem in your code is the `for` loop statement, which should be:

`for i = 1:length(raweeg{1,1}(:,1))`

Or better, `for i = 1:size(raweeg{1,1},1)`.

With out the "`1:`" part, it just has a single iteration, the last row.